# How to download files without full URL?

Tags: bash, wget, curl

I was always wondering how to download the files through the Linux shell (I have wget, curl) that do not have a full URL of the file to be downloaded, but the full URL is passed e.g. to the browser only when specific URL is visited. However, when I try downloading it through Linux shell (with either wget or curl), all I get is an HTML file.

For example, I'm looking to download several MB large file from here:

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/U00096.3&display=fasta&download=fasta&filename=entry.fasta

so when I paste this into the browser, I get the Save As dialog, offering me to save 'entry.fasta' file and not another HTML file. I tried curl -O -L -J as suggested in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/how-to-download-files-with-wget-where-the-page-makes-you-wait-for-download), but it didn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by *without full URL*? The link you provided works fine with `wget "URL"` and `curl -O "URL"`. Complete genome saved to disk. There is no redirect involved. (Did you remember to quote the URL?)

Comment: Oh damn... I never used the quotes, but yeah you're right. Thanks!

(I meant without a specific URL to entry.fasta.)

Comment: @Sukminder may as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your provided URL downloads fine using for example:

```
wget "URL"
curl -O "URL"
```

As mentioned in comments: quote. Always quote!

Letters like `&` has a special meaning in shells and the URL is not going to be interpreted as you want without them.

---

As for *downloading without knowing the file name* – I'm still not quite sure what you mean, but some notes:

This is ***site specific*** for ebi.ac.uk

The [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) provided is a special form of [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). You are most likely interested in the query part, and more specifically the first section: `U00096.3`.

You can change this to represent other files and ranges. for example to download `U00000` to `U00096` say:

```
curl -O "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/U00000-U00096&display=fasta&download=fasta&filename=U00000-U00096.fasta"
                                            ^^^^ data ^^^
```

The file name part is simply a suggestion on what to name the file. You can change this to anything you want. For example: `filename=myown.fasta` – is not going to change *what* is downloaded only what name is proposed by the server -> web-browser, and can also be used by curl etc.

---

There are a lot of search and listing possibilities on the site and you have to poke around.

#### More on what is happening

As you click the download link, or use tools like curl or wget a request is sent to the server at ebi.ac.uk for a specific file. In your example it likely has a referer set to:

```
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/U00096.3
```

and a GET query reported as:

```
query['display'] = fasta
query['download'] = fasta
query['filename'] = entry.fasta
```

The sever responds with something, among others, like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=entry.fasta
```

This is a way for the server to rely a suggestion for file name back to the client. If you use a curl version that has the `-J` option you can use this to save the file by this name: I.e.:

```
curl -OJ "URL"
```

---

#### As mentioned

This is quite site specific and the way the URL is interpreted on the server has to do with how the site is set up.

On a different host using another setup with a query part as `filename=foo.txt` could just as well be that you are served the an actual file named `foo.txt` from the server.

As for this site, ebi.ac.uk, the file is not a file but dynamically generated content using queries to databases. The result of the query is merged into a file and served to the end user.

Comment: Oh this an awesome answer, thank you so much!

Now I understand much better what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Without quotes, the shell sees the `&` and interprets that to mean "run everything in the line up to the & in the background, and then continue interpreting/running the rest of the line".  With quotes, the `&` is just part of the URL string.

There are three `&`s in your URL, so without quotes it would run four commands, the first three as background jobs:

```
wget http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/U00096.3 &
display=fasta &
download=fasta &
filename=entry.fasta
```

The fix is to quote the URL:

```
wget 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/U00096.3&display=fasta&download=fasta&filename=entry.fasta'
```

Single-quotes are fine here, but if you wanted to embed the value(s) of any variable(s) in the URL, you'd need to use double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarification! It totally makes sense when you write it line by line. I'm learning bash bit by bit too along the way too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could *carefully* use the [recursive download](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download) facility of `wget`. So if you

```
wget -r http://gcc-melt.org/
```

you'll download "every" reachable file from  `gcc-melt.org` site

<sup>(but read the [documentation of `wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html) before trying)</sup>

PS. I am the owner and author of the http://gcc-melt.org/ site so please don't overload it.